# Android - onActivityResult ignores stored byte

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that started another activity with `startActivityForResult`. In that other activity I changed a byte, and then I return to the original activity, storing the changed byte in an `Intent` before calling `finish()`.

Second activity:

```
public void goBack(View backButton){
    Intent previousPage = new Intent();
    System.out.println("open " + currentIndex);
    previousPage.putExtra("language", currentIndex);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, previousPage);
    finish();
}
```

First Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RETURN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent i = getIntent();
            currentIndex = i.getByteExtra("language", (byte)0);

            System.out.println("onactvityiresult " + currentIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

The byte was originally 0. I changed it to 1 in the second activity. System output however is:

```
10-09 19:00:34.519    9669-9669/com.example.admin.ghost I/System.out﹕ open 1
10-09 19:00:34.566    9669-9669/com.example.admin.ghost I/System.out﹕ onactvityiresult 0
```

If the byte is originally 1 and I change it to 0 in the second activity, the output is:

```
10-09 19:10:53.034  13437-13437/com.example.admin.ghost I/System.out﹕ open 0
10-09 19:10:53.331  13437-13437/com.example.admin.ghost I/System.out﹕ onactvityiresult 1
```

If I don't change the byte in the second activity, it correctly shows 0 and 0, or 1 and 1.

It is as if the First Activity keeps its original byte no matter what. How can I get the new byte passed to the First Activity?

Comment: you should provide the code, where you actually put that byte, I wonder how you assign it

Comment: @IliiazAkhmedov It's in there. `previousPage.putExtra("language", currentIndex);` , or is that not what you meant?

Comment: I meant what type is your currentIndex? Is it byte? If it is, how do you assign it to 1?

Comment: @IliiazAkhmedov it is gotten from SharedPreferences in onCreate. 
            `currentIndex = (byte) prefs.getInt("language", 0);`

Comment: No, I mean when you change the value in the Activity that is supposed to change the value, can you show how you store and assign currentIndex variable itself?

Comment: data, the 3rd argument, in onAcitivitytResult is having your currentIndex. not getIntent();

Comment: @Emma that was it. if you put it as answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data`, the argument of `onActivityResult`, is holding values from `setResult(RESULT_OK, previousPage)`.